# multiple onclick functions not possible?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm new to javascript (and I'm not allowed to use jQuery in class) and I'm struggling with onclick functions.

I want two separate sentences to turn green and the other one pink when I click on it so I gave both of them a different id.

```
for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
  var contentText = content[i];

  var opening = document.createElement("p");
  opening.id = "opening";
  if(content[i].id ==="opening"){
    opening.innerText = contentText.text;
  }
  textContainer1.append(opening);

document.getElementById("opening").onclick = function opening(){
  document.getElementById("opening").style.color = 'green';
}
```

This is the first onclick function and it works like it should! But when I add the other sentence underneath:

```
for(var j = 0; j < content.length; j++){
  var contentText2 = content[j];

  var second = document.createElement("p");
  second.className = "chapter-1";
  second.id = "second";
  if (content[j].id ==="second"){
    second.innerText = contentText2.text;
  }
  textContainer2.append(second);
}

document.getElementById("second").onclick = function second(){
  document.getElementById("second").style.color = 'pink';
}
```

The second one doesn't work anymore. I really can't figure out how to solve this and I need several ones in the same file. Can someone please help?

EDIT
I found out that it only works for the first thing in the json list, and not for the second, or third, etc. So I think I need a for loop to search within the elements, but I'm not sure how to do that in this case...

Comment: there is the loop over content in each. you give each iteration the same id. there are now many items `opening` and `second` with the same `id` attribute? the id should be unique in page. But When I have go guess, you don't want any loop. and: instead of assigning to the `onclick` property, you might want to use `.addEventListener('click',function(){...})`.

Comment: There is just one element per id, but they are inside a list of elements with different id's so I guess it has to search through it somehow?

Comment: There is *not* just one element per id. In your loops, the code *always* adds the elements to the DOM, whether or not the content entry matches.

Comment: `document.getElementById("opening").addEventListener("click", function f(){
  document.getElementById("opening"). style.color = 'green';
});`
I adjusted the first function to this and it works well. But the second still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

## New answer

I think you've missed a `}` in the first bit of code.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
  var contentText = content[i];

  var opening = document.createElement("p");
  opening.id = "opening";
  if(content[i].id ==="opening"){
    opening.innerText = contentText.text;
  }
  textContainer1.append(opening);
}
document.getElementById("opening").onclick = function opening(){
  document.getElementById("opening").style.color = 'green';
}
```

## Old answer with probably better code

I may be misunderstanding you, but if you want your sentences to go green/pink when clicking on them, you just need the second function in each of your examples.

```html
<p id="opening" onclick="opening();">opening</p>
<p id="second" onclick="second();">second</p>
<script>
var opening = function() {
  document.getElementById("opening").style.color = "green";
}
var second = function() {
  document.getElementById("second").style.color = "pink";
}
</script>
```

This makes opening go green when one clicks it and second go pink when one clicks it.
Alternatively, if you want to assign it without adding onclick in HTML:

```js
document.getElementById("opening").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("opening").style.color = "green";
}
document.getElementById("second").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("second").style.color = "pink";
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I mean! One question though, I would like to keep html out and include the onclick in the var opening that I mentioned above which already has the id = "opening". This is because my teacher doesn't want me to use html, but I'm not sure how to write it like that.

Comment: thank you! But this I already tried... and it doesn't work. It only works for my first element in my jsondataset and not for the others

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that much about DOM without some HTML already there.

Comment: I've changed it now; I think you missed a `}`